# What is the use of a "reuse" parameter of tf.contrib.layers functions?

Tags: tensorflow

While using some `tf.contrib.layers` functions, I found that the 'reuse' parameter of the functions does not work as I thought.

I thought that it would act similarly to the "reuse" parameter of `tf.variable_scope`.
Thus, I thought that it would raise an error if I try to use the function with `reuse=True` for the first time, or if I try to use it with `reuse=False` for the case it is already used before.

However, it seems not to emit any exception in the below cases:

```
# The first case
av = np.random.randn(3, 4, 5)
a = tf.Variable(av)
with tf.variable_scope('foo'):
    x = tf.contrib.layers.linear(a, 10, scope='bar', reuse=False)
    y = tf.contrib.layers.linear(a, 10, scope='bar', reuse=False)
sess = tf.Session()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
xv, yv = sess.run([x, y])
np.allclose(xv, yv)  # True

# The second case
av = np.random.randn(3, 4, 5)
a = tf.Variable(av)
with tf.variable_scope('baz'):
    x = tf.contrib.layers.linear(a, 10, scope='qux', reuse=True)  # don't emit an error
```

The same phenomena also occur at other functions that use `Dense` class internally.
It seems that it ignores the `reuse` parameter and always shares parameters if the name of a variable is same. Is this intended or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was most likely due to a [bug that was fixed in early 2017](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8626).  Updating to 1.1 or later should fix this problem.