# TensorFlow (v1.1.0) Multi-RNN BasicLSTMCell Error ('reuse' parameter) Python 3.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

An expansion on: [What is the use of a "reuse" parameter of tf.contrib.layers functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713266/what-is-the-use-of-a-reuse-parameter-of-tf-contrib-layers-functions).

The question: Although this issue has been brought up on github and will likely be addressed in another release of TensorFlow, I have found no existing solution for the time being; is there a stop-gap measure that might work in the meantime?

Code:

```
state_size = 4
def lstm_cell():
    if 'reuse' in inspect.getargspec(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell.__init__).args:
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(state_size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    else:
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(state_size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True)

cell = lstm_cell()
cell = rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=0.5)
cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
states_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, tf.expand_dims(batchX_placeholder, -1), initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
states_series = tf.reshape(states_series, [-1, state_size])
```

The function lstm_cell() is a suggestion from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py. It explains that the newest version of tensorflow has includes the 'reuse' parameter for BasicLSTMCell().

In this code, if I set reuse to `False`, tf.nn.dynamic_rnn line produces the error:

- "ValueError: Variable
  rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/weights already exists,
  disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally
  defined at:..."

If I set reuse to `True`, the error is:

- "ValueError: Attempt to reuse RNNCell
   with a different variable scope than its first
  use.  First use of cell was with scope
  'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell', this attempt is with
  scope 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell'.  Please create a
  new instance of the cell if you would like it to use a different set
  of weights.  If before you were using:
  MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...)] * num_layers), change to:
  MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...) for _ in range(num_layers)]).  If
  before you were using the same cell instance as both the forward and
  reverse cell of a bidirectional RNN, simply create two instances (one
  for forward, one for reverse).  In May 2017, we will start
  transitioning this cell's behavior to use existing stored weights, if
  any, when it is called with scope=None (which can lead to silent
  model degradation, so this error will remain until then.)"

Lastly, adding in 'scope=None' to dynamic_rnn provides no difference either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered trying what the 'reuse to True'-error is suggesting?

> If before you were using: MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...)] *
>   num_layers), change to: MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...) for _ in
>   range(num_layers)]).

following code snipped works for me (already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500797/6591278))

```
def lstm_cell():
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.NASCell(state_size, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=0.8)

rnn_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(num_layers)], state_is_tuple = True)
outputs, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cells, x, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```